# Charge and USB flash drive through same port

Tags: usb, external-sd, charging

I have a Pixel 3.  I'm trying to use an external USB connected microSD card for recording long videos in a vehicle.  However, even with wireless charging I'm finding that the power supplied is insufficient to keep the battery from draining.  I would like to therefore provide wired power, at the same time that the USB drive is connected.  How can I do this?

My first throught was some kind of USB hub, but then I realized that the phone will be accessing the device in on the go mode, not normal slave move. 
 Various bits of research suggest that [it's not trivial or standard](https://superuser.com/questions/1136336/can-i-use-a-usb-hub-to-simultaneously-charge-a-tablet-and-connect-a-usb-drive)

But it does seem to be possible.  I don't want to do any wiring, I just want something off the self.  One answer to the above linked question  specifically says:

> To have your tablet to be charged and simultaneously be in host mode, a special arrangement is required. In USB charging specification it is called "accessory charger adapter". For some more details you can see this item. However, your tablet must support this "accessory" mode, which may not be the case.

I don't even know how to tell if my device supports this mode.  The words "accessory charger adapter" are rather overloaded and Google returns a lot of completely unrelated stuff.

> ADDITION: The devices are available at Amazon with keyword search [OTG and charge at the same time]

I also tried this search, but am still no closer to finding something that should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can OTG HUB charge with connected charger more than 0.5A?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220032/can-otg-hub-charge-with-connected-charger-more-than-0-5a)

Comment: your external microSD card is connected via USB OTG so the problem remains the same - no charging in host mode

Comment: @alecxs That question doesn't seem to provide a clear answer on anything... I don't see a link to the actual device, but the answer seems to suggest that the product in question claims to support OTG and charging simultaneously... except that it apparently can't (is it lying?!)... except there are certain devices which it purportedly *can* do this with... except nobody seems to know where the list of devices is.

Comment: yes they lying.. for usb-c it may different https://android.stackexchange.com/q/194421

Comment: good luck https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+kernel+pixel+3+otg+charging+aca+mode

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, I'll need it apparently... I'm still on the Dec 2018 security release in the hopes that somebody will crack Verizon's stupid bootloader disabling so I can actually root my device.

Comment: just linking for future reference https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114070

Comment: @alecxs Thanks... it seems the keywords I am looking for are "USB-C Charging OTG Host", although so far it seems they are all micro-USB, not USB-C.

Comment: "This OTG hub can also charge your phone using the micro USB charging port adaptor and it can charge in two way" (lie - it can charge, but not same time in OTG mode) https://www.ebay.com/itm/153301609120